# Create correct inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have problem with creating proper inheritance between classes in Ruby On Rails.

Idea:
There are 2 classes: Person and Client. Person is a abstract class and Client inherits Person attribute.

Problem:
My solution doesn't work. I don't know why. How can I correctly implement (prefer CTI) inheritance.

Migrations:

create_persons.rb

```
class CreatePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :persons do |t|
      t.string :pesel, null: false
      t.string :first_name, null: false
      t.string :last_name, null: false
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.date :data_of_birth, null: false
      t.string :password_digest, null: false
      # required for STI
      t.string :type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :persons
  end
end
```

create_clients.rb

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      add_foreign_key :persons
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Model Person

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Model Client

```
class Client < Person

end
```

After db:migrate, when I try Client.create(pesel: "1232",....) there is error:
`unknown attribute 'pesel' for Client`.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/mvdamme/dbview_cti

Comment: Have you already considered going the composition route instead of the inheritance route?

Answer (score 1):

Single Table Inheritance is based upon having a single table to store all the records.
Your problem is that you create a table 'clients' which Rails uses by default for the Client class.

Just rake db:rollback on your last migration and it should look for the superclass table 'people' and work fine.

**Edit :** Oops, didn't see you mention CTI, this solution only works for STI.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because you've created a `clients` table in addition to your `persons` table. If you have a separate table for each class then the only thing that is inherited is the code and not the contents of the database.

[Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) (STI) allows you to add a `type` column and then instances of the parent class and subclasses will be stored in that single table *provided the expected table for the subclass isn't present*. You've added that `type` column but you've also created a `clients` table. This means that ActiveRecord is expecting you to store `Client` instances in that table instead of the `persons` - and when it tries to store a `Client` there it cannot use the field `pesel` causing your error.

So, if you want to use STI, then you need to remove your `clients` table and add an client-specific fields to your `persons` table.

Alternatively, you can keep your `clients` table and add the fields from `persons` that you want to also use for clients to the `clients` table. This wouldn't then be STI but your `Client` objects would inherit the methods from `Person`.

I suspect from your inclusion of the `type` field that you want to get rid of the `clients` table.